# Mule - can't see logs in Terminal when running Mule Standalone

Tags: maven, logging, terminal, mule, mule-studio

I'm developing a Mule application using Mule Studio 3.5.0, then packaging it with Maven (from Terminal) and deploying to Mule Standalone 3.4.0.  When I run my application from Studio I can see all of the logs in the console, however, when I run it from Terminal in Standalone mode I don't see anything past the following - yet my app still functions as expected. How can I get the logs to display in the Terminal window too?

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ Started app                'test-app'                    +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
INFO  2014-03-07 16:12:41,049 [WrapperListener_start_runner] org.mule.module.launcher.StartupSummaryDeploymentListener: 

**********************************************************************
*            - - + APPLICATION + - -            * - - + STATUS + - - *
**********************************************************************
* default                                       * DEPLOYED           *
* test-app                                      * DEPLOYED           *
**********************************************************************

INFO  2014-03-07 16:12:41,053 [WrapperListener_start_runner] org.mule.module.launcher.MuleDeploymentService: 
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ Mule is up and kicking (every 5000ms)                    +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

My log4j.properties file is as follows:

```
# Default log level
log4j.rootCategory=INFO, console

log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%-5p %d [%t] %c: %m%n

################################################
# You can set custom log levels per-package here
################################################

# CXF is used heavily by Mule for web services
log4j.logger.org.apache.cxf=WARN

# Apache Commons tend to make a lot of noise which can clutter the log.
log4j.logger.org.apache=WARN

# Reduce startup noise
log4j.logger.org.springframework.beans.factory=WARN

# Mule classes
log4j.logger.org.mule=INFO
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default application specific logging goes to the per-app logging, i.e ${MULE_HOME}/logs/${app.name}.log

If you want your application logs to go only to the console you can enable simpleLog as [explained here](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Logging+With+Mule+ESB+3.x)

If instead you want to log both in the application log and the console you should configure a console appender and a file appender within your custom application log4j configuration

Answer (score 1):

Look in ${MULE_HOME}/logs/mule_ee.log.  That is where console output gets logged.